# Source ggplot code and use within ggbio::tracks function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to use [ggbio::tracks function](http://www.tengfei.name/ggbio/docs/man/tracks.html) to have aligned Xaxis merged *ggplots*.

As *ggplot* scripts are complex they are saved as separate files which are then sourced to plot.

Here is one *complex ggplot* example script file, call it **test.R**, which will then be sourced:

```
# test.R
ggplot(cars,aes(speed,dist)) + geom_point(col="red")
```

Now, the problem:

```
library(ggbio)
library(ggplot2)

# complex ggplot script sourced text.R
x1 <- source("test.R")

# another complex ggplot script
x2 <- ggplot(cars,aes(speed,dist)) + geom_point(col="green")

# check classes
class(x1)
# [1] "list"
class(x2)
# [1] "gg"     "ggplot"

# this works
print(x1)
```

[image]

```
# this doesn't work within tracks function
tracks(
  print(x1),
  x2,
  heights=c(10,1)
)
```

> Error: Objects of type list not supported by autoplot.  Please use qplot() or ggplot() instead.

```
# below works - Note: x1$value
tracks(
  x1$value,
  x2,
  heights=c(10,1)
)
```

[image]

I am surely missing something very simple, I tried to play with *source()* options, but couldn't find a way to avoid using `$value` or `print()`. Essentially, I want to be able to run below code and get above merged plot:

```
# ideal code
tracks(
  x1,
  x2,
  heights=c(10,1)
)
```

Comment: Wow, that's quite a few dependencies ...

Comment: @Roland not sure I understand this comment.

Comment: I've made the mistake of installing ggbio ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ad-hoc solution: modify your `test.R` by wrapping it into dummy function like so

```
# test.R
test_ggplot <- function() {
  ggplot(cars,aes(speed,dist)) + geom_point(col="red")
}
```

and then

```
source("test.R")
x1 <- test_ggplot()
```

which obviously results in

```
class(x1)
#[1] "gg"     "ggplot"
```

Honestly, I've never seen usage of `xx <- source()` so I doubt it is advised to do so. There is even no `Value` section in `?source`...

Edit: `source` calls `withVisible`, which describes the return value exactly as a list:

> This function evaluates an expression, returning it in a two element
>   list containing its value and a flag showing whether it would
>   automatically print.

Comment: I think *source* returns as invisible? `invisible(yy)`

Comment: Nope, since `class(invisible(ggplot()))` is still `[1] "gg"     "ggplot"` :)

Comment: Regarding `xx <- source()`, we do not have to assign it to a variable, I assigned it to see the class it returns. `source("test.R")$value` works within *tracks*, but I want to avoid using `$value`. I will try to apply your solution to my case.

Comment: My experiments indicate that `source` returns a list with names `c("value", "visible")`, so within your approach there's no way around `$value` or `[[1]]`, I suppose.